# Missing mysql.sock while connecting mysql in Centos

Tags: mysql, centos6

I'm trying to connect to mysql in Centos. I was using this normally. But this morning i wasn't able to connect. Looked through various links on internet and got to know i'm missing mysql.sock. I looked through find command but all in vain.

Error:
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Are you sure your server is running ?

Comment: Yes Marco, server is running. I reverted back with the snapshot i took earlier and it worked now. Thanks. Closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answer. But reverted back to previous state using snapshot. And problem got solved.